# DeviceIoControl() with IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY is failing and returning error code 87. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deviceiocontrol

Relevant code is as follows:

```
std::wstring path = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data();

std::wstring testFileName = path + std::wstring(L"\\TestVariablySized");
this->hMappedFile = CreateFile2(
    testFileName.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    NULL);

uint32_t checkF = GetLastError();

DISK_GEOMETRY geo = { 0 };
DWORD bReturned = 0;

bool controlCheck = DeviceIoControl(
    (HANDLE)hMappedFile,              // handle to device
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, // dwIoControlCode
    NULL,                          // lpInBuffer
    0,                             // nInBufferSize
    (LPVOID)&geo,          // output buffer
    (DWORD)sizeof(geo),        // size of output buffer
    (LPDWORD)&bReturned,     // number of bytes returned
    NULL);

uint32_t check = GetLastError();
```

After this, `controlCheck` is false and `check` is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.  `checkF` is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, which shouldn't be a problem here.

As far as I can tell, I've called `DeviceIoControl()` in a way consistent with the [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365169.aspx).
, but clearly I'm missing something.  Your help is most appreciated.

Edit:

Per responses received, I altered things to be as follows:

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile2(
    L"\\.\PhysicalDrive0",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    NULL);

uint32_t checkF = GetLastError();

DISK_GEOMETRY geo = { 0 };
DWORD bReturned = 0;

bool controlCheck = DeviceIoControl(
    hDevice,              // handle to device
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, // dwIoControlCode
    NULL,                          // lpInBuffer
    0,                             // nInBufferSize
    (LPVOID)&geo,          // output buffer
    (DWORD)sizeof(geo),        // size of output buffer
    (LPDWORD)&bReturned,     // number of bytes returned
    NULL);

uint32_t check = GetLastError();

CloseHandle(hDevice);
```

Which should be closer to being correct, even if it's not quite correct yet.  `checkF` is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which I found strange.  I tried `"\\.\PhysicalDrive1"` and `"\\.\PhysicalDrive2"` as well, but receive the same result.  `controlCheck` is still false, but check is now `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Comment: AFAIK, `IOCTL_DISK_*` only works if you open the disk itself, you can't send those to open handles for files inside volumes inside the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, I've called `DeviceIoControl()` in a way consistent with the `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` documentation

Actually, you are not, because you did not pay attention to this tidbit of the documentation:

> *hDevice*
>   A handle to the **disk device** from which the geometry is to be retrieved. To retrieve a device handle, call the `CreateFile` function.

You are not passing a handle to a **disk device**, you are passing a handle to a **filesystem path** instead.

When calling [`CreateFile2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx) to get a handle to a **disk device**, you need to specify a physical device in `\\.\PhysicalDriveX` format instead, not a filesystem path.

Also, as the [`CreateFile2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx) documentation says:

> The following requirements must be met for such a call to succeed:
>
> - The caller must have administrative privileges. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.
> - **The `dwCreationDisposition` parameter must have the `OPEN_EXISTING` flag.**
> - When opening a volume or floppy disk, the `dwShareMode` parameter must have the `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flag.

You are using `OPEN_ALWAYS` instead of `OPEN_EXISTING`.

Please read the "Physical Disks and Volumes" section of the [`CreateFile2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx) documentation more carefully.

Try something more like this instead:

```
std::wstring path = L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
DWORD errCode;

hMappedFile = CreateFile2(
    path.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    NULL);

if (this->hMappedFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    errCode = GetLastError();
    // handle error as needed...
}
else
{
    DISK_GEOMETRY geo = { 0 };
    DWORD dwReturned = 0;

    bool controlCheck = DeviceIoControl(
        hMappedFile,                   // handle to device
        IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, // dwIoControlCode
        NULL,                          // lpInBuffer
        0,                             // nInBufferSize
        &geo,                          // output buffer
        sizeof(geo),                   // size of output buffer
        &dwReturned,                   // number of bytes returned
        NULL);

    if (!controlCheck)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();
        // handle error as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        // use drive as needed...
    }

    CloseHandle(hMappedFile);
}
```

Comment: @MNagy: that is because your input string to `CreateFile2()` is wrong, so it fails, returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and setting the error code to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. You are not checking for any failure, so you are passing that invalid handle to `DeviceIoControl()`, which is why it reports an `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error.  Your input string is using a **string literal**, so you need to escape the slashes by doubling them, eg:  `L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"`.